# How to make apt-get use gpg > 2.1 ? in ubuntu 16.4

Tags: ubuntu, gnupg, elliptic-curve

I am trying to use apt-get on a source that is signed with a GPG ECC (NIST P-256) key which requires gpg version > 2.1

how can i make apt-get use gpg2 instead of gpg? (aliasing does not work)

```
root@fa2e16b8fbc3:/£ gpg --version
gpg (GnuPG) 1.4.20


root@fa2e16b8fbc3:/£ uname -a
Linux fa2e16b8fbc3 4.4.66-boot2docker £1 SMP Fri May 5 20:44:25 UTC 2017 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux


root@fa2e16b8fbc3:/£ cat /proc/version
Linux version 4.4.66-boot2docker (root@607924cbbc93) (gcc version 4.9.2 (Debian 4.9.2-10) ) £1 SMP Fri May 5 20:44:25 UTC 2017


root@fa2e16b8fbc3:/£ cat /etc/issue
Ubuntu 16.04.3 LTS \n \l

root@fa2e16b8fbc3:/£ apt-get install  gnupg
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
gnupg is already the newest version (1.4.20-1ubuntu3.1).
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 0 not upgraded.


root@fa2e16b8fbc3:/£ gpg2 --version
gpg (GnuPG) 2.1.11
```